# Does a certain exponential decay implies polynomial decay?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let $\phi:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ be an increasing function and $\phi(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty.$ Is it always true that if $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|e^{\phi(|x|)}<\infty$$ then $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|x^m<\infty$$
for any non-negative integer $m$?

Comment: No, $\phi$ could be essentially $\log(\log x)$...

Comment: Right. Thank you